# Which open-source recommendation system should I choose to deal with big dataset

Tags: hadoop, recommendation-engine

I want to build a recommendation system, and the target is to deal with really big data set, like 1 TB data.

And each user has really huge amount of items, however the number of user is small, like thousands or 10 thousands.

I have search from google, I found there is some open-source recommendation engine based on hadoop like **Mahout**, I guess it may have ability to deal with such big data, however I'm not sure.

I also find some engine write in C++ python, even php, I don't think script languages can deal with such big data, cause memory can't contain the whole dataset.

Or I'm wrong? Could some give me some recommendation?

Comment: Yes, Mahout would be right option for you.  With Mahout-collaborative filtering, you can build scalable recommnder system over distributed systems to handle very big datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title is:

> Which opensource recommendation system should I choose to deal with
>   big dataset?

and in the first line you say

> I want to build a recommendation system, and the target is to deal with really big data set, > like 1 TB data.

And you are asking for an recommendation as an answer.

To answer your second question first. In my experience of building recommender systems I would advise you do not "build" a recommender system from the ground up if you can avoid it. Recommender Systems are complex and can use a wide range of techniques to provide a user with a recommendation.  So my recommendation is unless you are really committed, and have a team of people with a range of experience and knowledge in recommender systems, statistics, and software engineering then look to implement an existing recommender system rather than building your own.

In terms of which open source recommender system you should choose, this is actually pretty difficult to answer with great accuracy. Let me try to answer this by breaking it down.

1. Consider the open source license, its restrictions and your requirements.
2. Consider which algorithm you want to use to make recommendations
3. Consider the environment you will be running your recommender system on.

I recommend you look more into the algorithm side as it will be the determining factor as to which tool you can use, or whether you will need to roll your own. Start reading here  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-recommender1/ for a very brief insight in to the different approaches that recommender systems use. In summary the different approaches are:

- Content based
- Neighbourhood / Collaborative filtering based
- Constraint based
- Graph-based

In your case to keep things relatively straightforward it sounds like you should consider a user-user collaborative filtering algorithm for this. The reasons being:

1. Neighbourhood Collaborative Filtering is quite intuitive to understand and it can be *relatively* easy to implement.
2. With this method you can also justify your recommendations to your users in a basic way
3. There is no requirement to build a model for training, and the processing of neighbours can be done "offline", to provide quick recommendations to the end user.
4. Storing neighbours is actually quite memory efficient, which means better scalability. Something it sounds like you will need lots of.

The user-based part of my suggestion is because it sounds like you have less users than you do items. In a user-based nearest neighbourhood a predicted rating of a new item I for user U is calculated by looking at the other users who have also rated item I and are most similar to user U. Because you have fewer users than items in your system it will be faster to compute user-based collaborative filtering compared with item-based collaborative filtering.

Within the user-based collaborative filtering you need to consider what rating normalisation (mean-centering vs z-score) you want to use, the similarity weight computation method (e.g. Cosine vs Pearsons correlation vs other similarity measures) you want to use, neighbourhood selection criteria (pre-filtering of neighbours, number of neighbours involved in the prediction), and any Dimensionality Reduction methods (SVD, SVD++) you want to implement (with a large dataset like yours you will want to seriously consider DM).

So really instead of looking for an open source that will be able to process your data set you should consider your algorithm choice first, then look to find a tool that has an implementation of this algorithm, and then assess whether it can process your the volume involved in your dataset.

In saying all of that, if you do choose to go down the user-based collaborative filtering route then I am confident that Apache Mahout will be able to solve your problem, and if not it will certainly help you understand the complexity involved in building your own (just look at their source code).

Please note the advice is really consider the algorithm choice. "Good" recommender systems are so much more than just being able to process a large dataset. You need to think about accuracy, coverage, confidence, novelty, serendipity, diversity, robustness, privacy, risk user trust, and finally scalability. You should also consider how you are going to perform experiments and evaluate your recommendations, remember if the recommendations you are churning out are rubbish and it is turning your users off then there is no point to have a recommender system!

It is such a big area with lots to think about, there is probably no one single tool that is going to help you with everything, so be prepared to do a lot of reading and research as well as implementing lots of different open source tools to help you.

In saying that, start looking at Apache Mahout. Going back to the break-down of the 3 areas I said you should think about.

1. It has a commercial-friendly open-source license,
2. it has really great implementation of the algorithms you are likely going to need to use, and
3. it can work on distributed environments (read scalable).

Hope that helps, and good luck.